# Split graph into largest two subgraph based on node weight

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

Given this network which is basically a radial network with weights on each node:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0, weight=10)
G.add_node(1, weight=5)
G.add_node(2, weight=7)
G.add_node(3, weight=8)
G.add_node(4, weight=13)
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
```

I am trying to split graph G in the two largest subgraphs, where size is defined by the weights of the nodes. The split would eliminate edge (1,3) and produce two subgraphs with nodes [0,1,2] and [3,4].

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
edges = list(G.edges())
weights = list(G.nodes(data='weight'))
node_weights = []
for i in weights:
    node_weights.append(i[1])

con_comp = []
edge_split = []

for i in edges:

    G.remove_edge(i[0],i[1])
    edge_split.append((i[0],i[1]))
    a = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))

    b = list(a[0].nodes())
    bw = []
    for j in b:
        bw.append(node_weights[j])
    c = list(a[1].nodes())
    cw = []
    for j in c:
        cw.append(node_weights[j])

    sum_b = sum(bw)
    sum_c = sum(cw)
    con_comp.append((sum_b, sum_c))

    G.add_edge(i[0],i[1])

diff = []

for i in con_comp:
    diff.append(abs(i[0]-i[1]))

val = min(diff)
ind = diff.index(val)

remove = edges[ind]
```